# Next step if i complete work before time

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

I am a Front end developer. I am sometimes assigned task that i do before time, therefore i ask my manager to check it. Is it a good idea to ask your Reporting Manager or Project Manager to have a look, making him jump off his seat to come and look at the work or it is better to do it and keep it aside while i do something that is good for me i.e study online or watch tutorial.

In both cases i just don't want to sound bad, because *when i call my manager to have a look, it remind me of time of school, when you use to call you teacher to ask you have done your work first.* :P

Comment: This is "ask your manager" territory. If they give you only a single task at a time they may want to check your work with you as that doesn't make much sense otherwise. But you'll have to ask him.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to call them over every time. If you've finished your tasks, send them an email or IM asking if they want to take a look before you release the latest version. If they do, arrange time that works for them.

Whether they want to look or not, ask them what your next priority should be. That way, you can continue working without interruption and they can look at your work when convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can also notify your manager *before* your task is finished.

If you see you have X days<sup>*</sup> of work left, send your mail X days ahead of time.

That's still no guarantee that (s)he will show up at that exact time, but it helps everybody plan ahead and reduce slack time.

<sup>* X can be a fraction</sup>

Comment: The risk here, of course, is that some unforeseen problem occurs and the manager shows up and you are not done when you said you would be.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the answer is a combination of JohnHC and Jan Doggen's answers.

If you think you're going to be done with a task early, alert the person who would assign out your next set of work (Project Manager most likely).

> Hey PM, I think I'm going to finish my task in the next day or two and will have bandwidth to pick up something else. What would you like me to work on next?

*[keep a record of the work you complete early, and mention it in your performance review]*

Whether or not you need someone to look it over is likely going to be based on company process, and/or your experience and reputation. That would be a question for either or both your Reporting and Project Manager. Best practice is generally to have a code review (a senior dev reviews your code to ensure it's up to standards, edge cases are handled, you're not doing something O(n^n) where O(n) would suffice, etc.), and a task verification (someone reviews the work you did and the exit criteria and ensures the software now does what the task described).

Comment: Typically i know in and outs. I do have to see a lot of code that is badly written just to make things work, but i do have to work to make it look pretty visual wise, while cleaning the code as well.